# Screen for allowing pets in/out for a cracked/partially open door?

Tags: doors, screens

I let my cat out in the backyard and want her to be able to come back in whenever, but I don't want to leave the door open all the time, so I leave it cracked, i.e. about 6 inches, to try to keep bugs (and some of the heat/cold) out.  Are there any products or DIYs to put a screen across the 90% of the cracked opening, since the cat only needs a small portion of that opening to get in and out?

Comment: try this:https://www.amazon.com/PetSafe-Plastic-Small-Tinted-Paintable/dp/B000MD59IS/ref=asc_df_B000MD59IS/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=167141013968&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=12762091580238231979&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9012306&hvtargid=pla-304560215026&mcid=1ff2d19b72793c369b06e490e8a6ffa5&gclid=CjwKCAjwnv-vBhBdEiwABCYQA-y_piPmcFJsG4X-2wHZ2KlQ4GD2SPKU7YOD31kF3Sa3TGcy3FznHxoCaNoQAvD_BwE&th=1          Most people do not like the idea of leaving a door cracked open, so the screen is not a viable possibility.

Comment: You may be able to buy screening and make something. However it would need to be put up and taken down, so again something not desirable to most people.

Comment: I used to see ads for walk though screens, but the pet door is probably a better idea.